# Google Analytics 4, data deletion request for page path with email ID in query params

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

A google analytics newbie here.
Supposing I have accidentally stored email address as a query parameter only in one page path (let's say `loginState/?email=abc@abc.com`). I see that google analytics has a "Data Deletion Request" which can help in removing PII between certain dates.

How can I remove all page views for this page path? -> /loginState using this data deletion request feature.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the data removes all the data of that type for that day (and the previous or next day is not to be excluded, probably for a matter of time zone). In your case all page in that day.

The deletion is therefore not surgical.

https://www.analyticstraps.com/richiesta-di-eliminazione-dati-ma-con-laccetta/